# Help me to find a simple 3D game development tutorial in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal, unreal-4

I am looking already several hours to find a UE4 tutorial that creates a simple 3D game from scratch, but not using Blueprint. Instead I would like to see complete C++ tutorial. Cannot find any resource! Maybe unreal gurus can help on this? A single link of a game from scratch that is being created using C++ with UE4.

Comment: Is there any specific thing you're looking to do? e.g. Project creation, objects, ai, publishing, etc.

Comment: I want to create space shooter simple game like this one: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial without using blueprints.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't use blueprints?

Comment: @ZEKE They are slow. And I want max control. And I am fluent developer in C++.

Comment: I'd recommend adding that to your question then; it makes it easier to understand what exactly  you're looking for.